# How to skip a function

Tags: function, python-2.7

I am learning python and trying to make a little game. So my question is can you define a function but skip it and use it later.
EX.

```
def func()
    print"1,2,3,4"
func()

def func2()
    print "counting"
    func()
func2()
```

How would I skip func but still be able to print it later?

Comment: That's how *all* function definitions work in Python. What's your question, specifically? Some sample code would help.

Comment: That's how *all* function definitions work in any language at all.  That's kind of the point of a function definition.  And programming.  And computers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I you're asking what I think you're asking, then yes. In fact, that's the whole point. Functions are sections of reusable code that you **define** first (they don't run when they're defined!) and then you **call** that function later.

For example, you can **define** a function, `helloworld` like this:

```
def helloworld():
    print "Hello, world!"
    return
```

At this point in the program, nothing happens. You can then **call** the function like this:

```
helloworld()
```

At this point, `"Hello, world!"` will output to the console, and you can call the function as many times as you like!

Answer (score 0):

you are not using a function until you call it from somewhere else in your code.

For example, if this is your function:

```
   def myFunction():
       do something here
       return something
```

Then this function will not execute its code until you call the function from somewhere like this:

```
print myFunction()
```

This is a REALLY basic example but is it what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

suppose you define a function in a class:

```
def myFunction():
       do something here
       return something
```

it is defined now. when ever you want to use it. you need to call it by typing:

```
myFunction()
```

in your main method.

Now when you say skip it after defining it. it means you don't want to call it so it wont execute. it will just stay as unused but someday you call it it will start executing.

But if you are not using anything you don't need to write it in the first place. But for any reason if you do so its okay. your code will still work.